# Show/Hide configuration field in Magento 2

Tags: system.xml, magento2.4.1

In Magento 2 if we need hide/show the field in the same group we will fallow as below.

```
<section id="custom_general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>General Options</label>
                    <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                        <comment>Enable/Disable</comment>
                    </field>                
                    <field id="depends_on_file" translate="File Name"  sortOrder="5" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enter the File Name: </label>
                        <depends>
                            <field id="active">1</field>
                        </depends>
                    </field>              
                </group>
</section>
```

If we use `<depends>` it will act like show/hide based on active field.

In my case fields are in the different **tab sections** and I used the same `<depends>`, but not working for me. For this I used below method.

```
<section id="custom_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
             <group id="custom_customer_general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                 <field id="file_name" translate="File Name"  sortOrder="5" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enter the File Name: </label>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="custom_general/general/active">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field> 
            </group>           
        </section>
```

I used the `<field id="custom_general/general/active">1</field>` validation to show/hide, but it's not working.

Can you please suggest me if I went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
<section id="custom_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <group id="custom_customer_general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>General</label>
         <field id="file_name" translate="File Name"  sortOrder="5" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Enter the File Name: </label>
            <depends>
                <field id="*/*/active">1</field>
            </depends>
        </field> 
    </group>           
</section>
```

**add this file set value**

> etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <custom_customer>
            <general>
                <active>0</enable>     
            </general>
        </custom_customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Is this work dynamically? when we switched tab.